# Error Deploying Node.js Application on Render: 'ENOENT' npm Package.json Issue

Tags: node.js, npm, deployment, render.com

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0En4.png)
I'm encountering an 'ENOENT' error while trying to deploy my Node.js application on Render.
The error message states that npm cannot find the package.json file at the specified path '/opt/render/project/src/package.json'. However, my package.json file exists locally in the directory where I'm deploying from(C:\Users\shaik\Desktop\PROJECTTT>).Don't know why render is looking for package.json in '/opt/render/project/src/package.json' path. I've checked the file paths and ensured that all necessary files are present in the repository. I've also reviewed Render's documentation and troubleshooting resources, but I haven't been able to resolve the issue.
Everything seems right to me , I could be mistaken. Could someone help me understand why this error is occurring and how I can resolve it?

I'm looking for guidance on how to solve this error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.